# Where clause depending of the value of a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I have 2 fields I want to send values to within a `WHERE` statement.

- If a variable = 0 then set 2 field values to 100.
- If the variable = 1 then set those same 2 field values to 101.

In my imaginary world, somehow this would work:

```
Where CASE WHEN @ReportType = 0 THEN 
    od.StatusCd = 100 AND odm.StatusCd = 100
WHEN @ReportType = 1 THEN 
    od.statusCd = 101 AND odm.StatusCd = 101
End
And od.CompletionDate between ....
And so on....
```

I know this is wrong. But this is where I am at right now.

Comment: You are close, you can use OR around the conditions with no CASE.

Comment: where/what comparisons you are doing after sending values ? if i understand it correct you are just assigning values and no proper usage of 'where'.correct me if i got it wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I have understood what you are trying to do, this should work :

```
Where 
(
(@ReportType = 0 AND od.StatusCd = 100 AND odm.StatusCd = 100)
OR
(@ReportType = 1 AND od.statusCd = 101 AND odm.StatusCd = 101)
)
And od.CompletionDate between ....
And so on....
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could rewrite your CASE conditions in the form of a join, like below:

```
...
INNER JOIN
  (
    VALUES (0, 100, 100), (1, 101, 101)
  ) AS v (ReportType, odStatusCd, odmStatusCd)
ON
  @ReportType = v.ReportType
  AND od.statusCd = v.odStatusCd
  AND odm.StatusCd = v.odmStatusCd
WHERE
  od.CompletionDate between ...
  AND ...
```

Although somewhat less readable, this would avoid using `OR` and thus might result in a better (more efficient) execution plan. (You would need to test that.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do

```
WHERE od.StatusCd = 100 + @ReportType AND odm.StatusCd = 100 + @ReportType
```

Or you could declare a new variable with the value in:

```
DECLARE @StatusCd = 100 + @ReportType
```

Keep it simple.

Comment: Oops, this showed up as new activity, and I didn't notice it was such an old question. Nevertheless I think I'll leave this answer here, since I think it adds value!